# Difference between “have to aware” and " have to be aware"

Tags: grammaticality

Actually, I'm confused about the structure:"have to be"
As the title mentioned, Can anybody explain for me the such difference.

Comment: _Aware_ is a predicate adjective (like _asleep_) and therefore needs an auxiliary form of _be_. After the modal idiom _have to_, which requires an infinitive, that form is in fact the infinitive form _be_. Therefore _is/was/are/am/were/be/being aware_ is the required form.

Comment: As for _have to_, it's an idiom and a [modal paraphrase](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/aue/modals.html) and means the same thing as _must_. It has a [special pronunciation](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/aue/hafta.html); it's /'hæftə/ or /'hæftu/, **never** /'hævtə/ or /'hævtu/.

Comment: Thanks you very much. I can't vote for your comment because of comment position.

Comment: Thanks anyway, but don't worry about it. I have almost enough points now to get a cup of coffee, if I add some money.

Comment: After posted this question. I looked up dictionary and found aware as a adj. So I'm realize the role of "be" . But I'm not sure about it.  I'm learning IELTS by myself. My village haven't education center, but luckily, this site help me a lot. Thanks for everything.

Comment: @johnLawler On this side of the Pond I don't think your pronunciation advice holds true.

Comment: And we drink tea.

Answer (score 3):

In this context "have to be" is synonymous with "must be". "Have to aware" makes no sense.

Comment: Actually, I cannot realize what the role of "be" in phrase" have to be". I hope it will be clear for me

Comment: There ***is*** no role of "be", since there is no phrase "have to be"; the  construction is "have to" + "be aware". *"I breathe"* → *"I have to breathe"*. *"I am aware"* → *"I have to be aware"*.